# Projectile damage not being cancelled

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm trying to cancel the damage of an arrow if a player's name is in the list `noPVP`.

```
@EventHandler
public void playerDamagesWhenToggledOff(EntityDamageByEntityEvent e) {

    Player victim = (Player) e.getEntity();
    Player damager = (Player) e.getDamager();

    if (getter.noPVP.contains(victim.getName()) || getter.noPVP.contains(damager.getName())) {
        e.setCancelled(true);
    }
    else if (e.getCause() == DamageCause.PROJECTILE && getter.noPVP.contains(victim.getName()) || getter.noPVP.contains(damager.getName())) {
        e.setCancelled(true);
    }

}
```

This just doesn't seem to work, even when the `if` statement is fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it. / Your answer is in another castle.

Comment: Brilliant. Good for you! Just because your answer is incorrect, you close the post. StackOverflow is as bad as people say.

Comment: It works for melee damage only, as described in the description. It just doesn't work for arrow damage. How is it unclear?

Comment: "Whatever the problem with your code is, you've failed to demonstrate it in the code snippet" There? That's saying it's pretty unclear.

Comment: I'm not revoking my close vote by your attempt to attack me (or Stack Overflow, but I don't really care for it), nor am I convinced that you have an understanding of your own code. Therefore, I have no interest in keeping up this discussion of going back and forth. -1'd for no research effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the player takes projectile damage despite being in the `noPVP` list is the way with which you cast the entities. Note that both `e.getEntity()` and `e.getDamager()` return an `Entity` object and not a `Player` object. By always casting these variables you're telling the plugin that they are instances of the `Player` class without knowing what kind of entity they really are, which is often false because the damager and damaged entity can be other types of entities (arrows, animals, mobs, etc.).

To fix this you can make sure that in the certain case of an event being called, the damager or damaged entity are really instances of players by using the `instanceof` keyword. Below is an updated version of your code that should work:

```
@EventHandler
public void playerDamagesWhenToggledOff(EntityDamageByEntityEvent e) {
    if (e.getEntity() instanceof Player) { // If damaged entity is a player
        Player victim = (Player) e.getEntity(); // Cast
        if (e.getDamager() instanceof Player) { // If the damager is also a player
            Player damager = (Player) e.getDamager();
            // Check if either of them are in the list, if so -> cancel damage
            if (getter.noPVP.contains(victim.getName()) || getter.noPVP.contains(damager.getName())) {
                e.setCancelled(true);
            }
        // If the damager was not a player, we can check if it was a projectile using the damage cause
        // Still check whether damaged player is in noPVP list
        } else if (e.getCause() == EntityDamageEvent.DamageCause.PROJECTILE && getter.noPVP.contains(victim.getName())) {
            e.setCancelled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

In your original code, if a player shot an arrow at another player, your plugin tried to cast the arrow (the damager entity) to a player, which is not possible (the `Player` class is not a subclass of the `Arrow` class) thereby causing a `ClassCastException` and causing your otherwise correct code after the else-if statement to not be executed.

Here is the ClassCastException when a cow is damaged by an entity with your original code:[image: ClassCastException when damaging cow]

I added two print statements for debug purposes after the casting of the entities. Note that these statements are never reached (therefore never displayed) in the case of the ClassCastException being thrown but are displayed if both entities happen to be players and no exception is thrown.

[image]

With the code snippet I posted above, if a player's name is in the noPVP list any projectile damage is cancelled: [image]

Note that this cancels the damage of all projectiles if the damaged player is in the noPVP list. To only cancel the damage in the case of an arrow, you can check whether the damager entity is an instance of the `Arrow` class. You can even check whether the arrow was shot by a player or an entity such as a skeleton using `arrow.getShooter()`, once you've cast the damager entity to an arrow.

Comment: Sorry, but that wasn't the reason :/ Unfortunately doesn't work! But thanks for the detailed answer, I still learned alot.

Comment: Hey, I always test the code that I post so it's almost guaranteed to work. I'm sure it has to do with the way you implemented the code snippet or something else that's missing in your plugin. I would love to take a look at your updated code if you edit your original question!

Comment: +1 for in depth answer. However, learn to only post in real questions next time, instead of questions without a specific reproducible problem.

Comment: Actually, sorry the code was great! Thanks for the answer!